# How to migrate the syntax from @Html.RadioButtonFor to @Html.DropdownlistFor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

How to migrate the syntax from @Html.RadioButtonFor to @Html.DropdownlistFor?

I have to migrate some of our syntax which has Radio Button listing to dropdown listing. This is due to page screen spacing issue.

Changing the syntax from RadioButtonFor to DropdownlistFor doesn't help.

```
 <div class="col-sm-1">


                            @foreach (var item in Model.LevelList)
                            {
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TimesPerDay, item.ID, new { @id = "TimesPerDay" + item.ChoiceText }) @:  @item.ChoiceText
                            }

                            <span asp-validation-for="TimesPerDay" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a list of items that you want in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Model.ExcersiseLevelList picks the data and getting populated on Radio Button. But it is not happening for Dropdown list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a viewmodel property which has type of `List<SelectListItem>` and pass it to view as `DropDownListFor` option list (or `<select>` tag helper depending on your choice):

**Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    // other properties

    public List<SelectListItem> ExerciseLevelSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult ActionName()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();

    // data processing logic here

    model.ExerciseLevelSelectList = model.ExerciseLevelList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.ChoiceText,
        Value = x.ID.ToString() // string conversion if ID has numeric value
    });

    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

Using HTML helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TimesPerDay, Model.ExerciseLevelSelectList, ...)
```

Using [`select` tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper):

```
<select asp-for="TimesPerDay" asp-items="Model.ExerciseLevelSelectList"></select>
```

Note that `Value` property of `SelectListItem` instance has `string` type (check [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/SelectListItem.cs)), hence `ToString()` is mandatory if you want passing numeric value to that property.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TimesPerDay, Model.ExerciseLevelList.Select(e => new SelectListItem() { Text = e.ChoiceText, Value = e.ID.ToString() }))
        <span asp-validation-for="TimesPerDay" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

See reference: [SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.Object%29)

I'm not sure you're easily able to apply html attributes for every dropdown list item individually (but you can do it simply for the whole dropdown with method overload)

Comment: @goofyui what exception exactly?

Comment: Added e.ID.ToString() - you can check it again

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NewMode, new SelectList(Model.PaymentModeList, "PaymentModeDescription", "PaymentModeDescription"), "Select Mode", new { @class = "inputtext width200px" })%>                    

</div>
```

Comment: thanks.. but the task is completed.. i might have used the code advise from Tetsuya..,